# Are “restricted stock units” equivalent to money printing?

Tags: stocks

My friend recently received 1 million dollars worth of stocks for mid level software engineering position?

I would like to know if it is equivalent to money printing?

Can the employer just give whatever figure in stocks? Or are there checks and balances in stocks?

Comment: Typically, the stock comes from a pool of shares specifically reserved for that purpose, rather than being made available for sale on the open market. In that sense, they've already been "paid for", as they *didn't* raise money for the company in the first place.

Comment: @chepner That does not make sense to me. Let's say we have a company like Microsoft. It went public in the 80s. Since then, it has hired thousand of employees. It is only going to grow in future, so how many stocks can you possibly reserve?

Comment: No because they aren't actually money. "1 million dollars" is the real-world equivalent of clickbait.

Comment: @user253751 its not clickbait. My friend legit got that many stocks.

Comment: @RohitGupta He received a certain number of stocks. He didn't receive a million dollars.

Comment: @user253751 he can encash those stocks after they vest in few years.

Comment: @RohitGupta Will he get a million dollars after they vest in a few years? Or will it be a different amount?

Comment: @user253751 yes, he will get a million dollars. Are you not aware of the concept of stock options?

Comment: Who will give him a million dollars in a few years after they vest?

Comment: @user253751 he can sell them in the stock market after stocks vest.

Comment: @RohitGupta Stock options and RSUs are very different things. Options give you the opportunity to *buy* stock at a discount, so your only profit is the difference between the strike price and what you can eventually sell the stock for. RSUs turn into shares immediately on vesting (compare to an option with a strike price of zero). Companies can also use part of their equity or cash to create new shares. It's not printing money; it's just converting one asset into another.

Comment: Both options and RSUs are measured in units, not cash. The cash value depends on what you can sell the shares for once they vest.

Comment: @RohitGupta Who will spend a million dollars in the stock market to buy them? How do you know they will spend a million dollars?

Comment: @user253751 you're being deliberately rude and unhelpful. Of course the value will fluctuate over the vesting period but if it is a publicly traded liquid stock they will have no  problem cashing out

Comment: @windwally He may be able to cash out, but what has an expected value of $1,000,000 today may not be worth anywhere near that when they finally vest. Whenever I've been given a choice, it was between 4X options or X RSUs. You get fewer RSUs precisely because they will be worth *something* when they vest (assuming the company still exists), whereas options may be worthless if their market value dips below the strike price fixed at issue.

Comment: @windwally Often it's not a publicly traded liquid stock. Publicly traded companies with liquid stocks usually have enough money that they don't need to pay people in stock. So again, how do you know someone will be willing to pay a million dollars, instead of just one dollar?

Comment: @user253751 nothing has indicated that we're talking about a startup or something. RSUs are more often used by public companies, and we know that the company is at least large enough to have multiple tiers of engineers, so we're looking to answer for the likely scenario. Certainly that's better than continuing to flood the comments with obtuse rhetorical questions. Also, companies don't issue RSUs because they "need to pay people in stock", its more about retention, incentivizing employees to stick with the firm.

Comment: In the US, I believe RSUs are taxed as income when they are granted/vested? $1M of RSUs may incur a hefty tax bill. Or is that only after a section 83(b) election?

Answer (score 7):

No - issuing stocks (or options) does not *create* wealth or money - it *transfers* it. Stock represents a partial ownership of an entity. If a company gives stock to its employees as a bonus, that is an expense to the company and dilutes the ownership of the existing stockholders, since the size of the pie is the same but there are now more pieces.  *Usually* either the diluting factor is so small that it's not harmful, or (for startups) investors accept that this is a reality of how the company compensates employees.

So it's not "money printing" - there is no infinite supply of shares to distribute, and as shares *are* distributed, the value of those shares goes down.

Comment: Note that if the stocks are not liquid, you might find they are worth significantly less than you were told.

Comment: @user253751 That's true, and may be germane to the specific situation, but not relevant (IMHO) to the root question about issuing stock "creating money". And I think that point has been made in the comments to the question.

Comment: Lets say, I am an employee and I have 100 shares. The company hired 1k more employee. They all get x amount of shares. it shouldn't dilute my stake. But based on your explanation, it will dilute my stake. Could you please clarify it for me?

Comment: There's a lot of "it depends" in the answer - companies can have shares that _aren't_ diluted when new shares are added.  To continue the pie analogy - let's say half of the pie is fixed and the other half is divvied up to new employees and the public. Then stock compensation will dilute the half that is traded publicly and not the half that is "fixed".  If your shares are in the "dilutable" half, then yes your share would get diluted.

Comment: If you ever saw "The Social Network" this is what happened to Eduardo Saverin - his shares were part of a "dilutable" class and when shares were created for new investors his share was diluded drastically.

Comment: @RohitGupta You may have read that distributing new shares is typically 'non-dilutive', meaning old shareholders don't lose value. When this is true, it is because those shares are issued for the fair value of old shares. ie: if you have 100 shares out of 10,000 shares total, you own 1% of the company. Assume that company is worth $1M - so you effectively have shares worth $10,000. Now assume 1k people after you are each also granted 100 shares. You still own 100 shares, but with 100,000 new shares issued, you own 100/110,000 shares = ~0.1%. This is dilutive.

Comment: HOWEVER If those new employees added ~10M in new value, you would own ~0.1% of a company worth ~11,000,000, or about the same $10,000 in value. That would be non-dilutive. While hiring new employees is necessary and surely adds value, I would think in most cases the issuance of new shares would itself be considered dilutive, and hopefully subsequent company growth from new hires would bring the old shareholders back into the same value or more.